# Rails form_for sending params to controller action and not model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

In the controller `review_queue` I have a custom action that posts a result to a target URL, I want to build a form for this action. I am not going to save any of the fields to the DB I am just going to pass them in the params to the `post_review` action.

```
def post_review
  RestClient::Request.execute(:method => :post,
                              :url => Rails.application.secrets['target_url'],
                              :content_type => :json,
                              :payload => @result_params.merge!(params[:reasons]).to_json,
                              :headers => HEADERS)
end
```

In the view I have a form that will be filled out and on submit it should send up the reasons when the form is submited, I am setting the `review_queue_id` and the `status` in the form, since these are static, but the reasons should come from the textarea

```
<%= form_for(:review_queue, url: { action: 'post_review', :review_queue_id => @review_queue.id, :status => 'accepted'} ) do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='comment'>Please give a reason? (required)</label>
    <%= f.text_area(:reasons, placeholder: 'Your commentns ...', rows: 9, class: 'form-control') %>
  </div>
  <div class='modal-footer'>
    <%= f.submit 'Approve', class: 'btn btn-success btn-decission btn-modal-left-side'  %>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

error message:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `reasons' for #<ReviewQueueApplication:0x007fa7ff7832d8>:
```

It seems as if rails is assuming the MVC architecture here, and assuming I want to pass the reasons to the `review_queue` model. there is no reasons column so it's dropping a no method error. Is there a way of specifying that the form is 'temporary' and only getting as far as the controller?

This seems like it should be a simple thing but there is some rails magic happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError - undefined method `reasons' for
>   ReviewQueueApplication:0x007fa7ff7832d8

`form_for` assumes that you are creating a form for a ***model object*** and expects the ***fields to be present*** in that specific ***model's table***(*in a normal situation*).

You should be going with `form_tag`

```
<%= form_tag post_review_path, method: :get, :review_queue_id => @review_queue.id, :status => 'accepted'} ) do |f| %>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='comment'>Please give a reason? (required)</label>
    <%= text_area_tag(:reasons, placeholder: 'Your commentns ...', rows: 9, class: 'form-control') %>
  </div>
  <div class='modal-footer'>
    <%= submit_tag 'Approve', class: 'btn btn-success btn-decission btn-modal-left-side'  %>
    <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller access it like `params[:reasons]`. Also if you noticed, I've added `method: :get` to the `form_tag` as you don't want to save the info to ***DB***

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @pavan. I see that the text area is now messed up but that's fine ill figure that out. at least i am seeing the params in the controller now :)

Comment: Would the form tag line not look like this? `<%= form_tag(post_review_review_queue_applications_path(:review_queue_id => @review_queue.id, :status => 'accepted'), method: :get) do |f| %>`

Comment: @TheLegend You should append the form to a route which you defined in the routes. Since your route is `post_review`, it will be `post_review_path`.

Comment: ok great stuff! thanks for rocking my socks this Saturday! you are the real MVP

Answer (score 1):

The rails helper form_for is used for forms for rails resources. You want to use the form_tag helper. Search for form_for and form_tag [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for more information on these 2 methods.

Comment: Thank you so much bud! i have never used form_tag before.